# excel bubble chart and line chart combined

Tags: excel, linechart, bubble-chart, combinedchart

I have a table below

[image]

I want to draw line chart to show the variation of price over date and also a bubble chart to show the volume of transactions on each date.The size of the bubble depends on the volume. The position of a bubble depends on the date and the price so that its center is on the line. How to do it in Excel. Here is an example, I managed to have by manually superposing two charts but it is not very precise.

[image]

Comment: As far as I know, what you have is good, but you need to adjust the formatting of the line chart. Make the chart transparent and get rid of the axes and grid lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code to edit the size of the markers based on the values. You may have to copy and adjust the values to a reasonable marker size in a dummy column, and hide/delete it after.

```
Sub ChangeMarkerSize()
    n = 10 'Number of Points
    For i = 1 To 10
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
        With ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points(i)
            .MarkerStyle = 8
            .MarkerSize = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & i).Value * 0.1
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```